# Iterate over Collection while removing elements from it

Tags: vb.net, collections

I am iterating over a collection and want to delete some entries of it. Example:

```
For i = 0 To Node.Nodes.Count
    If i >= args.TotalNumberOfNodes Then
        Node.Nodes.RemoveAt(i)
    End If
Next i
```

As you can see, if one condition is true, I want to delete the item from the collection. If I pass now a List of 20 items into this, what happens is that **every 2nd** element gets deleted for an obvious reason: If the item should be removed, it gets removed which decreases the list size by 1 and then `i` is incremented by one which leaves the then current element out.

Another (working) approach is:

```
For i = 0 To Node.Nodes.Count
    If i >= args.TotalNumberOfNodes Then
        Node.Nodes.RemoveAt(i)
        i = i - 1
    End If
Next i
```

This technique decrements `i` by 1 before it gets incremented at the end of the for loop resulting in the same `i` as before. Since this seems to me a bit like bad design and it is not completely easy to understand for readers, I would like to know if there is any better way to remove items from a list but not skipping the next item from this list.

In addition to this, with a for each loop it throws me an exception because it tries to iterate over the list which is currently being altered. On a different posting, I saw the approach of adding all to a new list and then using a `removeAll` method. This would work technically but for performance reasons I would like to manipulate the list as I walk over it.

Comment: If there are no threading concerns, and the code is localized, I'd probably do the decrement during traversal.  You won't be able to substitute for different iterators as easily, but if the code is localized, you can change it all right there if you choose a different iteration method.  Some languages allow deletion of the item referred to at the current position of the iterator so this is handled more naturally, of course, you'd be using a `foreach` instead of `for i`;  Other methods involve traversing backwards...

Comment: Interestingly, if I use a `for each` it deletes the current element, then jumps via `next` to the next element. This results in skipping every other element.

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with VB.Net's foreach constructs, thought it was like C#, my bad.

Comment: Let me try this out in C# and then come back to you.

Comment: C# gives me an InvalidOperationException if I try to modify the list I am iterating over, see https://github.com/f-ewald/ListIterationExample

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since lists grow and shrink from their end, you can easily solve the problem by simply looping over the list *in reverse order.*

```
For i = Node.Nodes.Count-1 To 0 Step -1
    If SomeCondition Then
        Node.Nodes.RemoveAt(i)
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: I accepted this solution because I think this is a general approach how to solve different problems when manipulating lists while iterating over them. Although I have to say that a decremented `i` feels not natural to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Do loop to perform the same task:

```
    Do
        myCollection.RemoveAt(MaxCount)
    Loop Until myCollection.Count = MaxCount
```

This will remove individual collection elements at your maximum count value.

There is also a `Do` ... `Loop While` variation of the loop.

You can find out more about [VB's loop structures here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezk76t25.aspx)

Comment: I like this solution a lot and it looks very clean to me.